# Select statement using primary key with no primary key

Tags: sql

Ok so I have a table for notes in my database and a table for users in my database.  Lets say notes table looks like this:

```
NoteId   NoteTitle    NoteAuth
--------------------------------
1        TempTitle    254
2        TempTitle2   871
```

and Users table looks like:

```
UserId   UserName
-------------------
254      Bob
871      Jim
```

How can I select from the Note table but select the NoteAuth as the UserName from the Users table.  Basically how can I use a primary key without a primary key being set up on the table.

Comment: One notable SQL guru said: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT Notes.NoteId, Notes.NoteTitle, Notes.NoteAuth
FROM Notes
INNER JOIN Users ON Notes.NoteAuth = Users.UserId
WHERE Users.UserName = 'Bob'
```

**Edit**

Here is a version that returns the user name for a specified note author.

```
SELECT Users.UserName, Notes.NoteId, Notes.NoteTitle, Notes.NoteAuth
FROM Notes
INNER JOIN Users ON Notes.NoteAuth = Users.UserId
WHERE Notes.NoteAuth = 254
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to select given a note id, and then select the word Bob, even though my select would actually give me 254.

Comment: What is the difference in Join and Inner Join? You use Join while another answer uses inner join.  Why that decision?

Comment: INNER JOIN and JOIN are equivalent in this case.  However, you didn't indicate which DBMS you're using, so I should have included the INNER keyword to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT NoteID, NoteTitle, UserName
    FROM Notes INNER JOIN Users ON Notes.NoteAuth = Users.UserID
```

There's no requirement for any keys to exist to use a column in a JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

```
select n.NoteId, n.NoteTitle, n.NoteAuth, u.UserName
from Notes n
inner join User u on n.NoteAuth = u.UserID
```

Answer (score 2):

The lack of a primary key will cause lack of table integrity. Now you won't be able to create a foreign key between the tables. This means that going forward you will be allowed to create a note with a user that doesn't exist in the Users table.

This won't stop you from

```
SELECT n.NoteTitle, u.UserName
FROM NoteTable n LEFT JOIN Users u ON n.NoteAuth = u.UserId
```

That will work in SqlServer.

The problem is is if you have a note that has a NoteAuth that doesn't exist in the users table, you'll end up with a NULL username. Use an ISNULL to replace NULL with something like 'No Username'.

But like I said, there won't be any integrity between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.Username, N.NoteTitle from Notes N, Users U WHERE N.NoteAuth = U.UserId
```